# How do I get the Outlook 2007 To-Do bar to color the same as my calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have set up color coding of meetings (ie appointments where [Required Attendees is not empty]) to show in my Outlook calendar in a different color and this is successful.

However, I can’t seem to find a way for these colors to reflect in the To-Do Bar. Only meetings I manually color through categorising in Outlook show in the same color in To-Do bar.

Answer (score 0):

If I read what you've done correctly it's because the automatic formatting in the calendar is not the same as assigning the meeting to a category. Automatic formatting just colours the entry rather than assigning a category of that colour and the To-Do bar only shows categories.

For incoming appointments, you could use a rule to assign a category to the calendar entry, but that wouldn't help you with things you set up for yourself with no attendees.